Installing Timeshift backup on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
How do I install the Timeshift Backup app on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS, as it's not listed in the App Snap Store? I want to use the GUI version of the app.
In earlier versions of Ubuntu I believe it was shown as a flatpak or deb, but 24.04 doesn't show it anymore.
Best way to install safely?

timeshift continues to be available in Ubuntu 24.04 as a .deb package. When you type in the search field and wait a little bit, the suggestion should appear in the drop down list. If you already pressed Enter before the drop down appeared, then you are in the search results screen, which defaults to "Snap packages". Change the filter from "Snap packages"  to "Debian packages" to see timeshift.
Using the command line instead, you can install it with
sudo apt install timeshift


Thank you! Also - yes - I waited a few seconds and it appeared as a Debian package file in the store. Needed to be a little more patient I guess.

@Jadeia Probably it is just the first time. Subsequent searches are almost instantaneous.

@vanadium sudo apt install timeshift doesn't work. Need to sudo add-apt-repository universe first.
